# Tightest convex set containing curves of length 1

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, curves

What is the smallest (either in terms of perimeter or area) convex shape in $R^2$ such that all curves of length 1 are properly contained within it ? I'm thinking a right triangle with sides of $1/\sqrt(2)$, but I'm not sure how to reason about this rigorously. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you allow candidate curves to be shifted and rotated?

Comment: This is an open question called [Moser's worm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser%27s_worm_problem). MathOverflow discussion: http://mathoverflow.net/q/32477